# Python Create hex file with unique data

Tags: python

I am trying to create a hex file with unique data such that if the file size is 1 MB, the file will have a hex equivalent of values from 1 to 1<<20, but the output file's size is 6.9 MB. I tried replacing `'wb'` with `'w'` but it didn't affect the file size.

```
f=open('/tmp/hex_data','wb')
    for i in xrange(1<<20):
        f.write(hex(i))
f.close()

$ ls -lrth hex_data 
-rw-r--r--  1 aameershaikh  wheel   6.9M Apr  5 16:43 hex_data
```

Comment: `f.write(hex(i))` writes a *minimum* of 3 characters: `"0x"` followed by the actual number as a hex. That number can be longer than a single character as well, i.e. `255` would be `"0xFF"`, 4 characters.

It is entirely unsurprising that your file ends up much larger than 2^20 bytes, since you write *at least* 3 times that many chars to it.

Comment: Is what you're actually after a file of N many random bytes? Otherwise - I'm not quite sure what you're after as what you're trying to do doesn't really make much sense...

Comment: how should i write such that 1byte=1hex char?@JonClement yes thats the end goal

Comment: @AamirShaikh You could strip off the `"0x"`, but you still have the problem that your values are much larger than what is displayable in a single hex character. The largest hex digit is `F`, which is 16. You are writing values of up to `2<<20`, which is `0x200000`, so 6 characters even ignoring the prefix. So you will have to either write fewer, or smaller values.

Comment: Is `f.write(os.urandom(2 << 20))` what you're after @AamirShaikh ?

Comment: @Zinki it's completely different - it writes N many random bytes - not the hex representations of each integer between 0 and that N.

Comment: @Zinki I'm taking a guess that's probably want they're after (and they've semi-confirmed) given they're expecting a file of N size. Otherwise, I'm not sure what else you'd want for writing each byte unless you truncate the range of integers to 8 bits (or something else)

Comment: {}f.write(os.urandom(2 << 20)) {} would not provide that much uniqueness

Comment: @AamirShaikh how can it - you can only have 256 possible values in the file. You could however then treat it as a file of 2/4/8/whatever byte integers though... it all depends why you're wanting to do this. It might help if you explained that a bit.

Comment: I need it for compression testing, a minimum compressible file

Comment: Are you actually trying to write bytes instead? How would writing hex numbers (ascii encoded, presumably) help you with compression testing?

Comment: @AamirShaikh Creating a file with minimum compressibility needs knowledge about the compression algorithm.  For any given algorithm the best way was shown already in the comments: Write random bytes.